# Ag-grid won't refresh rows via ngDoCheck even though the same code in ngOnChanges works

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Ag-grid successfully loads retrieved records when gridOptions onGridReady is invoked via ngOnChanges, but only loads the columnDefs  when invoked via ngDoCheck in exactly the same way (I can see the method is being called once I detect the changes using KeyValueDiffer/KeyValueChanges).

In the first case the rowData is passed via an input parameter, but in the second case, it's updated via a service property, whose changes are successfully detected by the modelDiffer code using onKeyChanges  The debugger goes to the this.gridOptions statement in ngDoCheck, but the table is not updated with the data's rows; only the column headers are displayed.

It seems like it has something to do with this.gridApi being defined when ngOnChanges runs but not when ngDoCheck() runs; the same behavior is seen with trying to set externalFilterChanged(), where it works fine in ngOnChanges() but the same exact code won't filter when run via ngDoCheck() andin that case this.gridApi is undefined when it gets to applying the filter (though the grid is already rendered in both cases).

ngOnChanges code (working):

```
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        this.gridOptions = {
            onGridReady: (params) => {
                this.gridApi = params.api;
                this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.model.records);
                this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs);
                this.gridOptions.columnApi.sizeColumnsToFit(4000);
                this.gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();
                this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells({ force: true });
                this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = this.defaultColDef;
                this.gridOptions.isExternalFilterPresent = this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this);
                this.gridOptions.doesExternalFilterPass = this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this)
            },
            rowSelection: 'multiple',
            enableColResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFilter: true,
        };
    }
```

ngDoCheck code (not working):

```
ngDoCheck() {
    const changes = this.modelDiffer.diff(this.model);
    if (changes) {
        this.gridOptions = {
            onGridReady: (params) => {
                this.gridApi = params.api;
                this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.model.records);
                this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs);
                this.gridOptions.columnApi.sizeColumnsToFit(4000);
                this.gridOptions.api.refreshHeader();
                this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells({ force: true });
                this.gridOptions.defaultColDef = this.defaultColDef;
                this.gridOptions.isExternalFilterPresent = this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this);
                this.gridOptions.doesExternalFilterPass = this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this)
            },
            rowSelection: 'multiple',
            enableColResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFilter: true,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your column definitions, i.e. `this.columnDefs` defined? That looks to be your problem.

Comment: They are defined by the same mechanism as this.model.records for rowData (propagated from a service when updated by another component); why do you say they're the problem if the column headers are correctly loaded in both cases while the records aren't loaded in the ngDoCheck case?